# array_combine php function doesn't preserve data type of string variable if the variable is int value

Tags: php, arrays

array_combine php function doesn't preserve data type of string variable if the variable is int value

A simple example :

```
$a = array('1', '2');
$b = array('first', 'second');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);
$ak = array_keys($c);
var_dump($ak);
```

This will produce output as : integer values of 1 and 2.

What i wanted is to preserve string type of values 1 and 2

for temporary, i have used :

array_walk to to eventually achieve what i want.

Comment: Why is it so important that numeric keys remain strings?

Comment: it is important because : this array is later on <code>json_encode </code> 'ed  and used in flash chart api for charts

Answer (score 4):

This is not because specific behavior of `array_combine()` function, but because of valid-[integer keys type-casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in PHP arrays:

```
$array = [1=>'foo', '2'=>'bar', 'x'=>'baz'];
var_dump($array); // 1 and 2 are int
```

There are also some other rules with keys type-casting (see link above).

However, there are some tricks to achieve string keys anyway, like:

```
$obj = new StdClass();
$obj->{'1'}='foo';
var_dump((array)$obj);//array(1) { ["1"]=> string(3) "foo" }
```

-but that is only for information - I would not recommend to use that. For your question, you can use something like `array_map()` applying it to result of `array_keys()` - but that will not save you - you'll not be able to determine which key was integer and which was string.